# Gradle doLast, doFirst behavior in copy task

Tags: gradle, copy, task

The

> **build.gradle**

```
task hello (type: Copy) {
   doLast {
      println "print from within"
   }
   println "print from outside"
}
```

when run

> **gradle -q hello**

the  **doLast{}** closure is not even touched. change **doLast** to **doFirst**, I get the same result:

```
D:\>gradle -q hello
print from outside
```

without the doLast or doFirst:

```
task hello (type: Copy) {
    //doLast{ 
       println "print from within"
    //}
    println "print from outside"
}
```

it works fine:

```
D:\>gradle -q hello
print from within
print from outside
```

This seems happening only with tasks of type Copy. can you please help clarifying? I am using gradle 2.4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run the task without `-q` switch you'll notice that the task is already marked as `UP-TO-DATE` - which means that no actions (and you add an action via `doLast`) were executed.

Why is that? In this particular example, you have configured no inputs and outputs for the task. `Copy` tasks resolve it's being up-to-date base on the inputs and outputs and since none were configured Gradle assumes there's no need for it to be run.

Comment: that explains partially. I have actually tried another use case: add **from:** and **into:** within the **doLast{}** closure. Think about what if the source file has changed contents, the purpose of the task is basically to update the destination. How can we achieve this? it really looks like the doLast {} won't be touched in a task of type copy, no matter what.

Comment: It does not make any sense to put both `into` and `from` within `doLast` since `doLast` will be run at *execution* time wheres `into` and `from` are used during *configuration* phase - in `doLast` it's simply too late to configure anything. Use `from` and `into` within task's body and it will work as expected. It also seems that you need to read about gradle basics. [Here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html)'s good starting point

Comment: my original post is specifically ask a question about tasks of type "Copy". I am still puzzled. this is a **build.gradle** file: `task mycopy(type: Copy){ from 'c:\temp\me.txt' into 'd:/' } <br> task hello(){doLast { println 'Hello, me'} } `. when you run **gradle build.gradle hello**, the code within **mycopy{ }** won't be run although it should be run in the configuration phase. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Heinz why it won't be run? How do you know it's nor running?

Answer (score 13):

I thought it would be helpful for the people who come to this place on the same question. Though the above explanation is conceptually making sense. There is no proper solution mentioned in the answer. Here is the solution on how i achieved `Copy` task with `doLast` execution.

```
  task hello () {
        doLast{ 
           copy {
             println "print from within"
           }
        }
        println "print from outside"
    }
```

This would provide the execution of copy task along with doLast.

`$ gradle -q hello
  print from outside
  print from within`

Hope this is useful.

Comment: You need to change copy { println ... } to copy { println "print from within"             from("x")  into("xx")  } if you run gradle 4.10, otherwise it complains about path being null. Please check this and update your otherwise very insightful answer.

Comment: Here is also good to mention that you removed the `task: Copy` from the definition of the task, otherwise it wouldn't have worked like this
`task hello (task: Copy) {`